# Comparing two variables in IF condition inside While loop in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, variables, do-while

i am trying to execute a IF condition inside a while loop, But the IF condition isn't working as variables aren't expanding! kindly guide me through the proper way to compare two variables in IF condition
**Note** - if you can see the error log - DATE was expanding thou!  problem with mdate

```
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
cat path/temp_b | while read file

 
do
    
    echo 'phase2'
    mtime=$(stat -c '%y' $Src_Dir/$file)
    echo $mtime
    mdate= echo $mtime | cut -d ' ' -f1
    echo $mdate
    echo $DATE
     if ["$mdate"=="$DATE"]; then
        "$file" > path/tempc
     else
        echo 'hi'
 
     fi
done
```

**Error log -

phase2

2020-05-07 05:22:28.000000000 -0400

2020-05-07

2020-07-21

./test1.ksh: line 37: [==2020-07-21]: command not found

hi**

Comment: http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Thank you! solved! :)

Comment: `mdate= echo $mtime | cut -d ' ' -f1` is not an assignment at all.

Comment: @Alekhyavarma : If you really posted here the exact, complete error message you got, this is not run by bash either.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement like:

```
if [ "$mdate" == "$DATE" ]; then
```

Explanation: `if` in `bash` needs to have square brackets, operator, and operand to be space-separated.

Comment: `==` is not guaranteed to work. To be portable it should only be `=`. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: ... Also, the OP's code has additional bugs this answer currently doesn't address.